# Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

Please help  me I am a beginner in Maven project I try to connect to my MySQL database with hibernate but I have this error. If anyone could help me 
it will be friendly!

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
    ... 19 more
```

This is my spring-database.xml for hibernate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/church" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="carthy-2" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.church.metier.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="HibernateUtil" class="com.church.util.HibernateUtil">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webmvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/webmvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/errors/error500.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/views/errors/error404.jsp</location>
    </error-page>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value> /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

my webmvc-dispatcher-servlet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">



    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="META-INF/messages/messages" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="localeResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <property name="defaultLocale" value="fr" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.church.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>

        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />



</beans>
```

and my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.agnc</groupId>
    <artifactId>church</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>church Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- MYSQL Connector -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.39</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>church</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Spring version is 4.1.7.RELEASE which does not support hibernate 5.Hibernate 5 is supported in 4.2.x plus version of Spring so, change the version of Spring to latest i.e 4.3.2.RELEASE which supports hibernate 5.

Comment: Hello thanks for your answers I changed the version of spring, but it does not work , I posted the project in my github
this the link:https://github.com/CaptainJava1991/church/blob/master/church.zip  can you see and tell me where is the problem please

Comment: I deployed your project successfully. No error in deployment. Where are you getting the problem?

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Comment: clean and build and then run. In dependency make sure that version of Spring is 4.3.2.  I ran your project in eclipse only and it does not give any error in deployment

Comment: Still the same problem when i clean build then run. Maybe is a maven mistake ? Should i clean m2 repository ?

Comment: you have checked the version of Spring jar file. is It 4.3.2? Will you please post snapshot of jar dependencies

Comment: yes this is 4.3.2 like in screenshot http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=16/35/xn9y.jpg

Comment: ClassNotFoundException is related improper inclusion of jar files. In below 4.2 Hibernate 5 was't supported so, that seemed to be the cause but 4.2.+  version supports hibernate 5 and problem should have been gone. In my system, I don't see any problem like that.  Alternatively you can opt for java configuration.refer to this   [link](http://websystique.com/spring/spring4-hibernate4-mysql-maven-integration-example-using-annotations/) for java configuration

Comment: Where I should specify the HibernateConfiguration.java file in the web.xml or in the webmvc-dispacher-servlet because I have a exception "org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found" and in the example there is not web.xml or webmvc-dipacher-servlet please help me

Comment: same error but for me it was missing spring-orm dependency

Answer (score 5):

In my case adding dependency for spring-orm helped. You can download it here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm