# ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm using spring 5 & hibernate5 integration.
 Running my app i get this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerDAO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:598)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
```

My pom.xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Spring_Hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring_Hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>5.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-cdi</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.15.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1-b04</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml</groupId>
            <artifactId>classmate</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My Spring.xml file:

```
 **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
           xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

        <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com_spring_hibernate.controller, com_spring_hibernate.dao, com_spring_hibernate.entity" />

        <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
        <mvc:annotation-driven/>


        <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

        <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:properties/database.properties"/>

        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"></bean>


        <!--define datasource, define factory which includes data source-->

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
            <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
            <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
            <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

Also my project includes: controller,dao/daoImp, entity and util classes.

I've checked some familiar posts which recommend to add spring-orm dependency (what i've already done and yet it don't help me).

Comment: It seems you have multiple versions of Hibernate on your project, in the `spring.xml` file you are referencing Hibernate 4 -> `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`

Comment: Updated that to hibernate5, still have same error

Comment: Check if you do not have conflicting Hibernate libraries (multiple versions)

Comment: I've added maven-enforcer-plugin into my pom.xml but after running my app i do'nt receive any msg about wrong compatibility.

Comment: Try remove all the Hibernate dependencies from your `pom.xml` and add just [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.4.1.Final)

Comment: Actually, i found out that i was wrong about maven-enforcer-plugin. It shows tons of errors, here are some of em:
[ERROR] 
Dependency convergence error for org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final paths to dependency are:
+-Spring_Hibernate:Spring_Hibernate:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.1.Final
    +-org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.2.Final
and
+-Spring_Hibernate:Spring_Hibernate:1.0-SNAPSHOT
  +-org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.1.Final
    +-org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.1.0.Final
 

But still how to resolve them ?

Comment: Run the following command on your project from the prompt: `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` and add the output to your question. Also give a try to my suggestion to remove all Hibernate libs and add the one I sent

Comment: I've deleted mine hibernate dependencies, added yours. Run from prompt: mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose Result:  BUILD SUCCESS.
But "Running maven Build" by myself still shows same errors;

The output before [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS is too long for to post it as message here.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to specify, you should run this command on your project folder :)

Comment: I've run it inside intelij IDEA "Execute Maven Goal" , with working directory that follows to current project and command line u sent before. Is it correct ?

Comment: You must get an output like the example in the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Comment: Yes, i've got output like that. It ends with: [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
I've just tried to run my project again and it doesn't show any errors, although if i try to "Run maven Build" it shows " [INFO] BUILD FAILURE " . How that's even possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find class \[org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean\] for bean with name 'hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39258018/cannot-find-class-org-springframework-orm-hibernate5-localsessionfactorybean-f)